# Adding a reload button to an Ajax page with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

In a jQuery Mobile application, I'm using Ajax to load a page with dynamic content. Now, I want to add a "reload" button to that page.

Consider `index.html`:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
  <div data-role="header"><h1>Home</h1></div>
  <div data-role="content"><a href="time.php">Time</a></div>
</div>
```

And `time.php`:

```
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="time">
  <div data-role="header"><h1>Time</h1></div>
  <div data-role="content">
     <p><?= date(DATE_RFC822)?></p>
     <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="refresh">Reload</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can now navigate back and forth between the "home" and "time" pages, and the time will be updated when arriving on the "time" page, but I would like the "Reload" button to reload the "time" page. That is: it should do an Ajax request for `time.php`, and recreate the "time" page from the response (and meanwhile show the "page loading" indicator).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the code of `changePage` and `loadPage` I came up with a simpler solution:

```
$('.reload').live('click', function(e) {
  $.mobile.changePage($.mobile.activePage.jqmData('url'), {
    reloadPage: true,
    changeHash: false,
    transition: 'none'
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note that JQM will still transition between the old version of the page and the new version; it is best **not** to use a transition that has a stronge sense of direction (like 'slide').

The `preventDefault` does not seem strictly necessary, but I added it for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be possible when using the hijax-style links. You can however use a multi-page HTML document and load the dynamic page content yourself in the `pagebeforechange` event.

So in `index.html`, I already add the "time" page with empty content:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
  <div data-role="header"><h1>Home</h1></div> 
  <div data-role="content"><a href="#time">Time</a></div> 
</div> 

<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="time"> 
  <div data-role="header"> 
    <h1>Time</h1> 
    <a href="#" class="reload ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-icon="refresh">Reload</a> 
  </div> 
  <div data-role="content"></div> 
</div>
```

Next, I intercept the `pagebeforechange` event: in case of the "time" page, we will load the page content from URL `time.php`.

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
    if(typeof data.toPage == 'string') {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage);
        if(u.hash == "#time") {
            loadPageContent($('#time'), 'time.php', data.options);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Since I want to wait for the Ajax request to come back before changing the page, I prevent the page change; `loadPageContent` will have to do this.

I can do a similar `loadPageContent` for the "Reload" button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#time .reload').bind('click', function(e) {
        loadPageContent($('#time'), 'time.php', undefined, $(e.target).closest(".ui-btn"));
    });
});
```

This is the code of `loadPageContent`:

```
function loadPageContent(page, url, options, button) {
    if(typeof button != "undefined")
        button.addClass($.mobile.activeBtnClass);
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg($.mobile.loadingMessageTheme, $.mobile.loadingMessage, $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible);
    var content = page.children(':jqmData(role=content)');
    content.load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if(status == "success") {
            page.page();
            content.trigger('create');
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            if(typeof button != "undefined")
                button.removeClass($.mobile.activeBtnClass);
            $.mobile.changePage(page, options);
        } else {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg($.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessageTheme, $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage, true);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                if(typeof button != "undefined")
                    button.removeClass($.mobile.activeBtnClass);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

This is already quite an elaborate version: it will display the page loading message, and it will display an error message for 1s when the request fails. At the end of a successful request, it will enhance the content with the `create` trigger, and it will do the page change. If the reload button is passed along, it will mark this button as active while the operation is in progress.